# How to add custom text to a website using a selfmade google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How am I able to add custom text to a website that can be added more than once under the same domain?

Examples:
steamcommunity.com/id/someone

Under their name, it would say: OFFICIAL

with a green color.

Thanks

```
html
`<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #status {
    white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
  }
</style>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<div id="status"></div>
<img id="image-result" hidden>
</body>
```

`

Comment: easy, start by creating the extension - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: It's already made! :D @JaromandaX

Comment: oh, so the problem is you don't know how to use `manifest.json`?

Comment: i did the guide, but dont know how to add text to websites, could you please help?

Comment: appreciated @JaromandaX

Comment: oh, I thought you'd already written the extension - perhaps you can show, **in the question not in a comment** the code you currently have written

Comment: Thansk, added @JaromandaX - keep in mind that I have all theese files: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted